# how to write marionettejs module using typescript?

Tags: typescript, marionette

I'm trying to write MarionetteJS module using Typescript. Compiled module should be added to plain javascript application using RequireJS and initialized as normal Marionette module i.e.:

```
define(
['marionette', 'modules/sample/sample'],
function (Marionette, Sample) {
    var sampleApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
    sampleApp.SampleModule = sampleApp.module("SampleModule", Sample.Sample);
}
```

My module is created, but initializer and start functions are not being called by Marionette.Appplication.

This is my TypeScript class:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="backbone" />
/// <amd-dependency path="marionette" />
/// <amd-dependency path="jquery" />
/// <amd-dependency path="underscore" />
/// <reference path="../../vendor/ts/backbone/backbone.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../vendor/ts/marionette/marionette.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../vendor/ts/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../vendor/ts/underscore/underscore.d.ts" />

export class Sample{

    constructor(public self:Marionette.Module, public app:Marionette.Application, public Backbone:Backbone, public Marionette:Marionette, public $:"jquery", public _:"underscore") {
        console.log("Sample.constructor");
        self.addInitializer(this.init);
    }

    init(options?:any) {
        console.log("Sample.init!");
    }

    start() {
        console.log("Sample.start");
    }

}
```

That code compiles to:

```
define(["require", "exports", "backbone", "marionette", "jquery", "underscore"], function(require, exports) {
    var Sample = (function () {
        function Sample(self, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
            this.self = self;
            this.app = app;
            this.Backbone = Backbone;
            this.Marionette = Marionette;
            this.$ = $;
            this._ = _;
            console.log("Sample.Sample!!!! %o %o", self, app);
            self.addInitializer(this.init);
        }
        Sample.prototype.init = function (options) {
            console.log("Sample.Sample.init!");
        };

        Sample.prototype.start = function () {
            console.log("Sample.Sample.start");
        };
        return Sample;
    })();
    exports.Sample = Sample;
});
```

while simple module written in javascript looks like that:

```
define(['text!./tpl.html'], function (tpl) {
    var Generic = function (self, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
        self.addInitializer(function (options) {
            console.log('Generic initialized %o', options);
        };
    };
    return Generic;
});
```

Can i write MarionetteJS module using Typescript? Does anyone has some examples? Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   class FoobarView extends Marionette.ItemView<Backbone.Model> {

        constructor(options?:any) {

            _.extend(options, {
               template: some_template_retriever_function('templatePath.html'),
               className: 'class-name'
            });

            this.behaviors = <any>{
                'somebehaviors' : {},
            };

            super(options);
        }

        serializeData():any {

        }

        show():void {
        }


    }

    export = FoobarView;
```

This will produce a module, after compiling, that can be imported directly to anything you name it

```
import FooBarView = require('Path/to/FoobarView');

// now you can instantiate this view

var view = new FooBarView({some:options});
```

of course, remember your typings reference at the top

```
/// <reference path="../../vendor/ts/marionette/marionette.d.ts" />
```

Comment: How can this code be unit tested? i have tried using a mocha with chai with similar piece of code but getting marionette undefined error in my unit test file

Answer (score 2):

Old Question, anyway, using TypeScript 2, requireJS, after several attempts & errors I made it work. **But before I list all the things I've done, I have to comment out your first code snippet that was**

```
define(
   ['marionette', 'modules/sample/sample'],
   function (Marionette, Sample) {
      var sampleApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
      sampleApp.SampleModule = sampleApp.module("SampleModule", Sample.Sample);
}
```

**I do not agree with this**, because you define a module using requireJS (using `require.define` and `Marionette.Module`
In my opinion, you should use either one of both, not both... as I would use requireJS to define a module, I would write your code snippet as

```
define("SampleModule",
   ['marionette', 'modules/sample/sample'],
   function (Marionette, Sample) {
      return new Backbone.Marionette.Application();          
}
```

**That being said, here's how I did it work**
Assuming you have a `require.config` that aliases marionette library like this

```
// file : require-config.ts 
require.config({
   paths: {
      "marionette" : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/3.2.0/backbone.marionette"
      // + all the other 3rd party JS libraries
   }
});
```

about your definition TS file for marionette, either, you define your own, either you use `npm install --save @types\backbone.marionette`.

*for the record, as my project relies on an older version of backbone.marionette, I had to write it on my own, based on what has been defined on the return of such npm command*
**using npm command, there's also some extra work to make it work-but that's defitiely not the purpose here**
Once you've done this, you can write your sample module as is

```
// file : SampleModule.ts
/// <amd-module name="SampleModule" />
import marionette = require("marionette");
export = new marionette.Application();
```

The transpiled Javascript code is

```
// file : SampleModule.js (transpiled code)
define("SampleModule", ["require", "exports", "marionette"], 
function(require, exports, marionette) {
    "use strict";
    return new marionette.Application();
});
```

and that's it-it looks the same as what is written if we have coded in JS