# Marionette Module using typescript

Tags: backbone.js, typescript, marionette

How to create marionete module using type script. I saw this [how to write marionettejs module using typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885260/how-to-write-marionettejs-module-using-typescript) but its not usefull for my case. I created module like

```
class TestModule extends Marionette.Module {
    constructor(options) {
        if (!options)
            options = {};
        var marionetteApp = new MarionetteApp();
        marionetteApp.module("myModule", {
            startWithParent: false
        });
        super("myModule", marionetteApp);
    }
}
```

but its shows error 
Unhandled exception at line 3561, column 5 in http://localhost/Scripts/backbone.marionette.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'initialize' of undefined or null reference

What Im doing wrong. I am new to Marionette and typescript. What is the correct procedure to create marionette module using typescript
My application code is

```
class MarionetteApp extends Marionette.Application {
    headerRegion: Marionette.Region;
    leftRegion: Marionette.Region;
    centerRegion: Marionette.Region;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.on("start", this.initializeAfter);
        this.addRegions({ headerRegion:"#headerContainer",leftRegion:"#leftContainer",centerRegion:"#centerContainer"});
    }
    initializeAfter() {
        //alert("started")
        this.headerRegion.show(new HeaderView());
        this.leftRegion.show(new leftView());
        this.centerRegion.show(new CenterView());
        var MyModule = new TestModule("Test");
        //MyModule.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue using following code. Wrapped module inside a class. Its working as expected. Please correct me if I am wrong and anyone knows the correct procedure

```
class TestModule {
mod: any;
constructor() {
    var marionetteApp = new MarionetteApp();
    this.mod = marionetteApp.module("myModule", {
        startWithParent: false,
        initialize: function(){
            console.log("initialized");
        },
        define: function () {
            console.log("defined");
        }
    });

    this.mod.on("start", this.onStart);
}
start() {
    this.mod.start();
}
onStart() {
    console.log("Module started")
}
```

}

initialization code

```
var MyModule = new TestModule();
    MyModule.start();
```